# Azure web jobs process big file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage

I have asp.net mvc website on azure, that he takes a large file from the user, processes the data and stores it in a database. The problem is that a lot of busy site and the user does not need data immediately, so I wanted to use azure webjob, but I do not know how to pass him HttpPostedFile and other data.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save uploaded file into Blob storage. Then have your WebJob to monitor Blob Storage for new files and do processing. Once WebJob is done, it can post a result of calculation back to blob storage or to a database (depends on your set-up).

If you need to pass extra data along with the file, you can save the file into blob-storage and post a message to a queue. Message can contain the extra data. And you WebJob to listen to the queue: once it picks up the new message from the queue, it will get the extra information and a reference to the new file. And do processing. Once done post results somewhere available  for your web-site (or send email to the user).

Comment: Look at the following sample which demonstrates something similar to what you are trying to do https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/PhluffyShuffy/ReadMe.txt